# How to detect on which keyboard a key was pressed on Windows?

Tags: windows, keyboard

I currently have the problem that my pc thinks a key is stuck, even though  no physical keyboard is connected (home theatre pc). First I thought of a Windows 10 issue and reinstalled Windows 7. Unfortunately the problem persisted.

There are several virtual keyboards. How do I detect or visualize which of these causes the stuck virtual key?

Comment: How do you interact with that PC? It might be that whatever peripheral you're using is sending a false signal? Which key is supposedly stuck?

Comment: @Seth I was using VNC to interact with the pc, but currently I just attached a usb mouse to it. There is no single key which gets stuck, but it has always been an alphanumeric one (currently it's the number 6)

Comment: Do you use some kind of remote on it as you're saying it's a home theater PC? If so, there might be a key stuck on it? As for detecting the device you could just check the device manager for input devices.

Comment: @Seth yes, I'm using an IR remote, but have already tried to disconnect it without the problem to disappear. Nevertheless some of the dvb-s tuners have (disconnected) ir support as well. there are about 15 "HID-conform device" and few "usb input device" entries, unfortunately without a specific name.

Comment: If you check the details of the devices you would get some more information (e.g. for one of my devices it's listing Port_#0002.Hub_#0005 as a Location). It's going to be tedious though. As far as I know the signal for an input doesn't contain it's source.